# javascript parse string between strings

Tags: javascript

I want to parse a string from inside another string, based on a start and end string pattern.

The example is parsing an ip address, however this could be any string, and not necessarily an IP.

Is there a better / more efficient way of doing this:

```
function parse(str,start,end){
    var ls = str.indexOf(start);
    if(str && ls !== -1) return str.substring(ls+start.length,str.indexOf(end,ls));
    return false;
}

var res = "wlan0: adding default route via 192.168.0.1";
console.log(parse(res,"route via ","\n"));
```

> 192.168.0.1

Comment: 'this could be any string' makes it very difficult. Is at least the postion fixed?

Comment: `Is there a better way`...you haven't explained overall objective

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could clean it up a little:

```
function parseSubstring(str, after, until) {
    var pos0 = after ? str.indexOf(after) : 0,
        posS = pos0 > -1 ? pos0 + after.length : str.length,
        posE = until ? str.indexOf(until, posS) : str.length;

    if (posE >= posS) {
        return str.substring(posS, posE);
    }
}

var input = "wlan0: adding default route via 192.168.0.1",
    part = parseSubstring(input, "route via ");
    // -> "192.168.0.1"
```

On a general note, don't return `false` if you don't actually want to return a Boolean value. This is not PHP, returning `false` to indicate an error is the Wrong Thing. If there is no defined result of a function, don't return one at all.

---

You could also augment the `String` prototype.

```
String.prototype.snip = function(after, until) {
    var pos0 = after ? str.indexOf(after) : 0,
        posS = pos0 > -1 ? pos0 + after.length : this.length,
        posE = until ? this.indexOf(until, posS) : this.length;

    if (posE >= posS) {
        return this.substring(posS, posE);
    }
}

var input = "wlan0: adding default route via 192.168.0.1",
    part = input.snip("route via ");
    // -> "192.168.0.1"
```

Note how not passing in the `until` argument translates to *"up to the end of the string"*. Passing the empty string in the `after` argument would translate to *"from the start"*.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using regular expressions. This could be a generic beginning (take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript) for a proper `RegExp.escape` method):

```
function parse(str, start, end) {
    var start_expr = RegExp.escape(start);
    var end_expr = RegExp.escape(end);
    var regex = new RegExp( start_expr + "(.*)(?=" + end_expr + ")" );
    var match = str.match(regex);
    return match[1];
}
```

You may have to adjust it for your needs, as regex might not directly accept some escape sequences you are used to (e.g. "\n" in your example).

Comment: You should not build regular expressions from raw strings. This is very error-prone. Strings [must be escaped](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3561493/18771) before you can use them in a regex.

Comment: I assumed `start` and `end` to be already escaped, if necessary (e.g. don't want the "$" to be escaped in the example). Thanks for pointing it out. I wouldn't use that regex to match a string at end of line, it was just to stay generic yet simple.

Comment: Well, according to the intended use the OP is showing, input strings are not escaped. Apart from that it's bad design if a function expects "specially treated" parameters. Because if you forget, your function breaks at run-time (compare: *the principle of least surprise*) -- And apart from *that*: If there already *were* defined regular expressions, nobody would need a separate function just to use them on a string, right? ;)

Comment: Of course you're right, in fact I wouldn't wrap that into a function in real life, again, I only wanted to be clear for the specific question, ended up with a mess instead. I think I'd better delete it

Comment: No, if you include proper regex escaping the answer is fine. You don't need to repeat the `Regexp.escape()` function, mentioning where it came from would be enough.